# How to separate one column into many columns in a .txt file?

Tags: r

I've been given a data set for a project that I need to reformat in order to work with it.

The problem is that all of the column names and corresponding values are mashed into one column in the file. As shown in the picture.

I'm new to R so I hardly know how to work with complex commands.

**My Questions:**
Is there a simple way to separate this from 1 column into 12 columns?

**Desire Output:**

1. I'll also need to remove the periods between the column names and the semicolons between the values.
2. I just need to be able to do basic statistical analysis on the table. 
   Thanks

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV0v6.png)
[image]

Comment: Please share your code or tries you already made. Please, DON'T post images of data or code. You can use ``` this char to quote information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your data is in one column, it is semi colon separated.  The `read.csv` function has the ability to accept a column separator:

```
df <- read.csv(file="path/to/your/file.txt", skip=1, header=FALSE, sep=";")
```

The above call will generate columns based on a `;` separator.  I skip the first line and ignore the header, because it is a single string.  You may manually assign the columns names via:

```
names(df) <- c("name1", "name2", ..., "name12")
```

Comment: Read.csv2 is using semicolon as separator per default. Same goes with write.csv2 and so on